# Is there a way to somehow group several symbols from different files together so that if one of them is referenced, all are linked?

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

A bit of context first.

I'm curently working on a modular (embedded) microOS with drivers, ports, partitions and other such objects represented as structures, with distinct "operations" structures containing pointer to what you would call their methods. Nothing fancy there.

I have macros and linker script bits to make it so that all objects of a given type (say, all drivers), though their definitions are scattered across source files, are disposed as in an array, somewhere in flash, but in a way that lets the linker (I work with GNU GCC/LD.) garbage collected those who aren't explicitly referenced in the code.

However, after a few years refining the system and increasing its flexibility, I come at a point where it is too flash-greedy for small to medium microcontrollers. (I work only with 32 bits architectures, nothing too small.) I was to be exepected, you might say, but I'm trying to go further and do better, and currently I'm doubting LD will let me do it.

What I would like to get is that methods/functions which aren't used by the code get garbage collected too. This isn't currently the case, since they are all referred to by the pointer structures of the objects owning them. I would like to avoid using macro configuration switches and the application developper having to go through several layers of code to determine which functions are currently used and which ones can be safely disabled. I would really, really like that the linker's garbage collection let me automatize all the process.

First I thought I could split each methods structure between sections, so that, say, all the ports' "probe" methods end up in a section called .struct_probe, and that the wrapping port_probe() function could reference a zero-length object inside that function, so that all ports' probe references get linked if and only if the port_probe() function is called somewhere.

But I was wrong in that, for the linker, the "input sections" which are his resolution for garbage collection (since at this point there's no more alignment information inside, and it couldn't afford to take advantage of a symbol - and afferent object - being removed by reordering the insides of the containing section and shrinking it) aren't identified solely by a section name, but by a section name *and* a source file. So if I implement what I intended to, none of my methods will get linked in the final executable, and I will be toast.

That's where I'm at currently, and frankly I'm quite at a loss. I wondered if maybe someone here would have a better idea for either having each method "backward reference" the wrapping function or some other object which would in turn be referenced by the function and take all methods along, or as the title says, somehow group those methods / sections (without gathering all the code in a single file, please) so that referencing one means linking them all.

My gratitude for all eternity is on the line, here. ;)

Comment: Since I have spent some time documenting and experimenting on the following lead, even though without success, I would like to expose here what I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't entierely satisfying, but for lack of a better way, that's what I went for:

It seems the only way you have to effectively merge sections from several compilation units from the linker's point of view is to first link the resulting objects together in one big object, then link the final program using that big object instead of the small ones. Sections that had the same name in the small objects will be merged in the big one.

This is a bit dirty, though, and has also some drawbacks, such as perhaps merging some sections you wouldn't want to be, for garbage collecting purposes, and hiding which file each section comes from (though the information remains in the debug sections) if, say, you wanted to split the main sections (.text, .data, .bss...) in the final ELF so as to be able to see what file contributes what amount to flash and RAM usage, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Since I have spent some time documenting and experimenting on the following lead, even though without success, I would like to expose here what I found.

There's a feature of ELF called "group sections", which are used to define sections groups, or groups of sections, such as if one member section of the group is live (hence linked), all are.

I hoped this was the answer to my question. TL;DR: It wasn't, because group sections are meant to group sections inside a module. Actually, the only type of groups currently defined is COMDAT groups, which are by definition exclusive from groups with the same name defined in other modules.

Documentation on that feature and its implementation(s) is scarce to say the least. Currently, the standard's definition of group sections can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-0690/chapter7-26/index.html).

GCC doesn't provide a construct to manipulate section groups (or any kind of sections flags/properties for that matter). The GNU assembler's documentation specifies how to affect a section to a group [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html).

I've found no evocation in any GNU document about LD's handling of group sections. It is mentioned [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D70146) and [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D56437), though.

As a bonus, I've found a way to specify sections properties (including grouping) in C code with GCC. This is a dirty hack, so it may be it won't work anymore by the time you read this.

Apparently, when you write

```
int bar __attribute__((section("<name>")));
```

GCC takes what's between the quotes an blindly pastes it so in the assembly output:

```
.section    <name>,"aw"
```

(The actual flags can differ if the name matches one of a few predefined patterns.)

From there, it's all a matter of code injection. If you write

```
int bar __attribute__((section("<name>,\"awG\",%probbits,<group> //")));
```

you get

```
.section  <name>,"awG",%progbits,<group> //"aw"
```

and the job is done. If you wonder why simply characterizing the section in a separate inline assembly statement isn't enough, if you do that you get an empty grouped section and a stuffed solitary section with the same name, which won't have any effect at link time. So.